# Recursive Staircase Problem but with path printing

Tags: c

I'm working on this recursive staircase problem where the total steps and the steps you can take at a time are variable in C. I've found this very good code that does exactly that, but unfortunatly it only prints out the number of solutions instead of all the different path possibilities. For example: 4 steps, 4 steps at a time:

```
1-1-1-1
1-1-2
1-2-1
1-3
2-1-1
2-2
3-1
4
```

That's the code:

```
int countWays(int n, int m)
{
    int res[n + 1];
    int temp = 0;

    res[0] = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int s = i - m - 1;
        int e = i - 1;

        if (s >= 0) {
            temp -= res[s];
        }

        temp += res[e];
        res[i] = temp;
    }

    return res[n];
}

int main()
{
    int n = 5, m = 3;

    printf("Number of ways = %d",
            countWays(n, m));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: because you are only returning the value of  the last element.  loop through the array at the end of your countWays function and print out each value.

Comment: `countWays()` does not call `countWays()`: it is not recursive.